# Which is the more desirable way to convert Object to Long in Java?

Tags: java, performance

I'm dealing with an API that returns `Object` when I ask for a property.

```
Object x = r.getProperty("id");
```

But I know for a fact that this property in particular is a `Long`. So these are the two options I'm weighing:

```
Long x = Long.parseLong(r.getProperty("id").toString());

Long x = (Long)r.getProperty("id");
```

Which one is preferred performance-wise?

Comment: Based on gut instinct alone - probably the second one. One fewer object to allocate space for and construct.

Comment: Why would converting it to string and then converting it back to long have better performance than just casting it to long

Comment: I though the same but I have always heard that casts are very expensive

Comment: This question discusses two specific alternatives, only one of which is a cast. The duplicate does not look like a good fit; voting to re-open.

Comment: What you heard about casts being expensive is a myth as far as modern Java engines are concerned. There is very little performance penalty to downcasting (and none whatever to upcasting--e.g., from `String` to `Object`).

Comment: What you heard about casts is nonsense. If the object already is a Long there is practically nothing to do except check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know for a fact that it's a `Long`, I'd definitely go with the cast. It's clearer and probably more efficient. If you're sure the return type is a `Number`, you can call `Number.longValue()`. If that's not either a certainty, then I might go with the parsing option to be safe and avoid the `instanceof` boilerplate.

Comment: Agreed, and I'm assuming casting would be quite a bit faster, although the speed of this operation probably doesn't have any actual influence on performance, unless your program has no IO at all.

Comment: Yeah, this question was more about curiosity than anything... the IO for sure is the slowest part of the program.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is faster, but it is not very forgiving: unless the value is actually a `Long`, the code is going to crash.

The first approach, on the other hand, will survive a change of type: if you later decide to use `Integer`, `String`, `Byte`, or some other type with a custom `toString` that prints a numeric value compatible with `long`, the code is going to work. Hence, the first approach is more robust.